# Hist in matplotlib: Bins are not centered and proportions not correct on the axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

take a look at this example:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 l = [3,3,3,2,1,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
 plt.hist(l,normed=True)
 plt.show()
```

The output is posted as a picture. I have two questions:

a) Why are only the 4 and 5 bins centered around its value? Shouldn't the others be that as well? Is there a trick to get them centered?

b)Why are the bins not normalised to proportion? I want the y values of all the bins to sum up to one.

Note that my real example contains much more values in the list, but they are all discrete.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should adjust the keyword arguments of the `plt.hist` function. There are many of them and the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) can help you answer many of these questions.

a. ) You can pass the keywords `bins=range(1,7)` and `align=left`. Setting the `bins` keyword to a sequence gives the borders of each bin. For example, `[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], ..., [5, 6]`.

b. ) Check your bin widths (`rwidth!=1`). From the `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` documentation:

> If True, the first element of the return tuple will be the counts
>   normalized to form a probability density, i.e., n/(len(x)*dbin). In a
>   probability density, the integral of the histogram should be 1; you
>   can verify that with a trapezoidal integration of the probability
>   density function:

This means that the area under your bins is summing up to one, but because the bin widths are less than 1, the heights get normalized in such a way that the heights don't add up to 1. If you adjust `rwidth=1`, you get a good looking plot:

```
plt.hist(l, bins=range(1,7), align='left', rwidth=1, normed=True)
```